# how to understand hardware accelerated canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I've read [a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/03/22/unleash-the-power-of-html-5-canvas-for-gaming-part-1.aspx) , and there's something call  hardware accelerated canvas
The code snippet is

```
// Setting hardware scaling
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
canvas.height = 200;
canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

I dont understand quite well here,How does it make sense ?
Won't it lower the quality of the content in canvas,like displaying a bigger pixel in it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, yes it will.

It's like running a game full screen with a lower resolution like 640x480.

There's another [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2012/04/06/modernizing-your-html5-canvas-games-with-offline-apis-file-apis-css3-amp-hardware-scaling.aspx) covering this.

> This is not specific to HTML5 by the way. Most of the modern console games are not internally computed in 720p or 1080p. Almost all of them render the game in lower resolutions (such as 1024x600 for instance) and let the GPU doing the scaling/anti-aliasing process. This could help you boosting the FPS in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be of lower resolution, but the post also says:

> ... we can work on a smaller resolution and let the GPU rescales the
>   result to fit the DOM object (**with a beautiful and free filter to blur
>   the result**).

In theory this technique supposed to improve performance without sacrificing quality too much. You may want to play with `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to achieve the best performance/quality ratio.